# Как отключить loop, если у слайдера не больше одного слайда?

Tags: javascript, swiper

У меня есть слайдер (swiper) и мне нужно убрать loop если только один слайд.
Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать такое событие:

```
  on: {
      init: function () {
        if ((this.slides.length = 1)) {
          this.destroy();
        }
      },
    },
```